# how to create url clean url with paging

Tags: php, .htaccess

hello i want create clean url

like this
   http://localhost:8081/olshop/products/category/[namecategory]/[paggingnumber]

example : http://localhost:8081/olshop/products/category/pants/1

this is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule index$                                          index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^products/category/([^/]+)/?$                   index.php?p=products&category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^products/category/(.*)\/(\d+)\$                index.php?p=products&category=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^detail/([^/]+)/?$                              index.php?p=detail_product&link_barang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$                                    index.php?p=$1  [QSA,L]     
</IfModule>
```

when i try like

http://localhost:8081/olshop/products/category/pants/

this work

**but not work 
when using paging (404 not found)**
http://localhost:8081/olshop/products/category/pants/1

help me thank's :)

Comment: You need to put the rule with the pagination above the rule without pagination.

Comment: When i try link not clean url, this work and not problem
http://localhost:8081/olshop/index.php?p=products&category=pants&page=1

but when i using clean url not work
http://localhost:8081/olshop/products/category/pants/1

i think i'm wrong code in .htaccess

Comment: What do you mean "not working" ?  please be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are escaping the $ in your Rule

```
RewriteRule ^products/category/(.*)\/(\d+)\$                index.php?p=products&category=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Remove the backslash and you will be fine

```
RewriteRule ^products/category/(.*)\/(\d+)$                 index.php?p=products&category=$1&page=$2 [L]
```